# Identify OpenVZ virtual machine from inside

Tags: virtualization, debian-lenny, openvz

Is there any way for me to identify which OpenVZ container I am in, from inside the container? I am working on a setup where OpenVZ machines shall boot the same (read-only) disk image, so I can not configure them individually in the file system. I need a unique identification for each of the virtual servers, to be used by scripts running inside the OpenVZ containers.

(I'm running Debian Lenny, BTW.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every container in an OpenVZ host has a unique Container ID, also known as its VEID. From within a container, you should be able to read its VEID like this:

```
awk '{print $1}' /proc/vz/veinfo
```

This ID should be constant for a given container, since it is associated with the container's `.conf` file that configures it for OpenVZ.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be that you can use the IP or MAC address of each VM to differentiate them and pass that value to your scripts.

Comment: Thank you for answer! HWaddr always looks loke this in the OpenVZ containers: "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00". The unique identifier will be used to configure networking (and other init.d stuff prior networking is configured), so in my situation, IP address will not work neither. :(

Comment: Another tought, the Hard drive is supposed to have a uuid field which should be different for each VM, but in any case you can get the IP first and then use that to personalize each container later.